# Duplicating in for loop causes weird multiplication

Tags: python, bezier-curves

I am trying to generate roads from curves that i have placed in the scene. I have three curves and a road mesh that I apply a curve and array modifier to through python. I also set the values of the modifiers through python.

In python I loop through all objects in the scene, and for each curve I duplicate the main road mesh and apply modifiers with the new curve as the target.

My problem is that for each road it duplicates the road by an amount of 2 * the previously duplicated amount. So for the first curve it makes one road, for the second curve 2 roads, and 4 roads for the 3rd curve so on so forth.

I am fairly new to blender programming, so I am certain i'm missing something logical, but I can't figure out what.

[image: Before operator execute]

[image: After operator execute]

Finally here's the code for the operator:

```
def execute(self, context):
    objects = bpy.context.scene.objects
    road = bpy.data.objects["Road"]

    for obj in objects:
        if obj.type == "CURVE":
            road = bpy.data.objects["Road"]
            bpy.data.objects['Road'].select_set(True)

            newroad = road.copy()
            bpy.context.collection.objects.link(newroad)

            bpy.ops.object.modifier_add(type='ARRAY')
            bpy.ops.object.modifier_add(type='CURVE')

            arrmod = bpy.context.object.modifiers["Array"]
            curvemod = bpy.context.object.modifiers["Curve"]

            arrmod.fit_type = 'FIT_CURVE'
            arrmod.curve = bpy.data.objects[obj.name]
            curvemod.object = bpy.data.objects[obj.name]

    return{'FINISHED'}
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to select the object before copying it, so `bpy.data.objects['Road'].select_set(True)` is redundant.

Instead of that you need to make the newly created object active before calling any bpy.ops to make the op function operate on the new object. But I guess, you can avoid call to ops altogether and simply call newroad.modifiers.new to create the modifier.

So that the modified code will look like this (this is not tested)...

```
def execute(self, context):
    objects = bpy.context.scene.objects
    road = bpy.data.objects["Road"]

    for obj in objects:
        if obj.type == "CURVE":
            # road = bpy.data.objects["Road"] # Already set above so not needed
            # bpy.data.objects['Road'].select_set(True) # Not needed

            newroad = road.copy()
            newroad.data = road.data.copy() # You might also want to copy the data block
            bpy.context.collection.objects.link(newroad)

            # bpy.ops.object.modifier_add(type='ARRAY')
            # bpy.ops.object.modifier_add(type='CURVE')

            # arrmod = bpy.context.object.modifiers["Array"]
            # curvemod = bpy.context.object.modifiers["Curve"]

            arrayModName = 'array'
            arrmod = newroad.modifiers.new(arrayModName, 'ARRAY')

            curveModName = 'curve'
            curvemod = newroad.modifiers.new(curveModName, 'CURVE')

            arrmod.fit_type = 'FIT_CURVE'

            # arrmod.curve = bpy.data.objects[obj.name]
            # curvemod.object = bpy.data.objects[obj.name]

            # obj is the same as bpy.data.objects[obj.name]
            arrmod.curve = obj 
            curvemod.object = obj

    return{'FINISHED'}
```

Comment: That worked! I'm still not entirely sure what wen't wrong logically, but I can see how this method works better. Thanks.

Comment: Glad that it worked. `bpy.ops` operate on the active object and the newly created object does not become active automatically. So I guess, the modifiers were getting created on whatever object was active at the time of executing the block.